# How to make the time like 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' when the xAxis's type is time?

Tags: date, echarts

When I use echarts to show a table, I make the `xAxis` type time. What ever I do, the label on the `xAxis` is like `MM-dd hh:mm`. So how could I make it `YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`?

The echarts version is the newest. I set the `maxInterval` 1000, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure the `xAxis.axisLabel.formatter`: [documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.axisLabel.formatter)

The example in the documentation itself shows a case that uses Date objects ; since the formatter supports callback functions, you can freely set the format with all the operations you need to make it work.